# Filename with special characters

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, special-characters

I am trying to create a view with a list of images.
This is my code:

```
<ul class="gallery">
   @foreach (string item in Model)
   {
      <li>
      @{
              string parameterValue = "/PhotoGallery/" + item.ToString(); 
       }
         <img src=@parameterValue height="180" />
     </li>
   }
</ul>
```

I have problems when the file name contains space.
Example:

```
 <li>
    <img src=/PhotoGallery/DSC_0901.JPG height="180" />
</li>
<li>

    <img src=/PhotoGallery/name with space.jpg height="180" />
</li>
```

I get the error:*NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http:// localhost:6538/PhotoGallery/name*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the double quotes it should be:

```
<img src="@parameterValue" height="180" />
```